# excel sorting code causing corruption

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have an excel file that in one of the VBA subs, has some code that sorts and entire table every time new rows are added. this sub works and the data sorts, but when i save the file, exit, and open it again it says the file is damaged and if i want to attempt to repair it. when it repairs the file it points to the sorting code as the problem. this is the code Im using to sort:

```
Dim destSheet As Worksheet: Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
lMaxRows = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 

    With ws.Sort.SortFields
        .Clear
        .add Key:=ws.range("A2:A" & lMaxRows + 1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .add Key:=ws.range("B2:B" & lMaxRows + 1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    End With
    With ws.Sort
        .SetRange ws.range("A1:S" & lMaxRows + 1)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

is there something inherently wrong with this code? thanks for the help!

Comment: With dummy data in my column A, and removing Option Explicit from the beginning of my macro, your macro works as it should with just a single workbook open, and I can save and re-open the workbook without a problem.  That said, and although it probably won't make a difference, I would change your `Set ws` line to refer to `ThisWorkbook`; add `Option Explicit` to the beginning of your macro; declare the data type for `lMaxRows`, and, under `Options`, set to `Require Variable Declaration`

Comment: what would changing it to thisworkbook affect?

Comment: It depends on whether you want to specifically reference `ActiveWorkbook` or `ThisWorkbook`.  If you specifically want to reference `ActiveWorkbook`, then leave it as is.  But you have declared `destsheet` as referring to `ThisWorkbook` and, even though you do not use that variable in this code snippet, I thought you might also want `ws` to refer to the same.  If not, then do not change it.  For example, if you want to be able to run the code on a different workbook than the one in which the code is located.